# What's the most effective way to execute a task some distant time in the future on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have an application on App Engine which is consuming some data. After parsing that data, it will know that it needs to execute something in a period of time - possibly not for a number of hours or weeks.

What is the best way to execute a piece of code after some arbitrary amount of time on App Engine?

I figured using [Countdown Millis](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis%28long%29) or [EtaMillis](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#etaMillis%28long%29) from a TaskQueue would work, but haven't seen any evidence of anyone doing the same thing, especially for such long time frames.

Is that the best approach, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to persist an object in the datastore with all of the relevant information for future processing (including when the processing for the object's data should begin), you could have a cron job periodically query the datastore with a date/time range filter and trigger processing any of the above objects at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 2):

We successfully use TaskQueue's countdown parameter for sending emails to customers 7 days after they registered and for number of other needs.

Task queues is core/basic API/service and are pretty reliable - my opinion it's a best way to go with task queues ETA/countdown unless you:

- need ability programmatically see what is in the queue
- need ability programmatically delete certain task from the queue

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the task queue as a scheduler.  There is a 30 day max eta declared in [QueueConstants](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueConstants#getMaxEtaDeltaMillis()) and applied in [QueueImpl](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r165/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueImpl.java).

```
  //Returns the maximum time into the future that a task may be scheduled.
  private static final long MAX_ETA_DELTA_MILLIS = 2592000000L;
```

> 1000ms * 60s * 60m * 24hr * 30days = 2592000000ms

```
 private long determineEta(TaskOptions taskOptions) {
Long etaMillis = taskOptions.getEtaMillis();
Long countdownMillis = taskOptions.getCountdownMillis();
if (etaMillis == null) {
  if (countdownMillis == null) {
    return currentTimeMillis();
  } else {
    if (countdownMillis > QueueConstants.getMaxEtaDeltaMillis()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("ETA too far into the future");
    }
    if (countdownMillis < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative countdown is not allowed");
    }
    return currentTimeMillis() + countdownMillis;
  }
} else {
  if (countdownMillis == null) {
    if (etaMillis - currentTimeMillis() > QueueConstants.getMaxEtaDeltaMillis()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("ETA too far into the future");
    }
    if (etaMillis < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative ETA is invalid");
    }
    return etaMillis;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Only one or neither of EtaMillis and CountdownMillis may be specified");
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

1. Enqueue a task with a delay configured as you mention. Have the task processing change datastore entries in a known way (for example: set a flag).
2. Have a stragglers low frequency cron job, to perform any processing that has somehow been missed by an enqueued task (for example: an uncaught exception happened in the task).

For this to work, ensure that the processing called by the tasks and cron job are idempotent.

Enjoy?

Answer (score -1):

I think taskQueue is a good strategy but has one big problem "If a push task is created successfully, it will eventually be deleted (at most seven days after the task successfully executes)." [Source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

I would instead use the [datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore#adding_data_post_and_display_ui_to_jsp). here is one strategy you can take:

1. Insert a record into datastore once you completed "parsing that data".
2. Check the current date against the create/insert date to see how much time has passed by since your job was completed/started etc
   (clearly, you don't want to do every minute etc maybe do it once a
   day or every hour)
3. Execute the next task that you need to  do as soon as condition in step 2 become passed your "arbitrary amount of time" you want.

Here is how you can add a record to data store...to get you started ..

```
    Entity parsDataHolder = new Entity("parsing_data_done", guestbookKey);
    parsDataHolder.setProperty("date", date);

DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
datastore.put(parsDataHolder)
```

Comment: This would result in running a backend instance for like... a week straight, just for one task.  That seems a little inefficient.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis  you are correct on my first answer, I updated my response. Thank you for taking the time to help me improve my answer. Also, if you vote me up that would cheer me up too :)